# How do set conditional "Provides" when RPM is installed

Tags: rpm, specifications

This may be impossible but I am asking anyway.  I want to create an RPM that will change the Provides based on the hostname of the machine it is being installed on..
For example, in my spec file, I want to make several subpackages based on what I expect the hostname of the machines will be (in our environment, the first four characters of the hostname denote its organization id)
ORG19999
ORG29999
etc

in bash, I would get ${HOSTNAME:0:4} and run that through a case.

For a spec file, is there a way to get that during the install and apply a subpackage that would set the "Provides:" based on what is returned.
Provides: ORG1
or
Provides: ORG2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible using standard RPM mechanism.

You can create empty rpm (this needs to be executed on that target machine) using [create-fake-rpm](https://github.com/xsuchy/create-fake-rpm):

```
create-fake-rpm build hostname-provides "${HOSTNAME:0:4}"
```

And then installing this package.